# Is there a more efficient way to perform this instead of using explode/implode?

Tags: php, url

This simple PHP function accepts a URL string and returns the directory:

```
function getDirFromFilePath($file) {
        $temp = explode('/', $file);
        array_pop($temp);
        return implode('/', $temp);
}
```

Example:

```
Input:  http://www.domain.com/directory/filename.jpg
Output: http://www.domain.com/directory
```

Just wondering if there is a more efficient way to perform this, perhaps like a regex would?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [`dirname()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), which works with URLs too:

```
dirname('http://www.domain.com/directory/filename.jpg')
```